# Write in specific point of a docx document using vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to modify a template document (docx) automatically, according to info I've read into some text files and I'm using VBA for this.The template document has a predefined record, which looks  like this:

```
description: first description which can take more rows
             ...
author: the author 
date: the date
...
```

What I need is copying the previous line below the first one, as many times as many text file I have, and complete each one whit info I've copied into strings. So,for example, if I have 3 text file I'll have the previous line three times, like this:

```
description: first description 
             ...
author: the first author
date: the date in the first file

description: second description
             ...
author: the second author
date: the date in the second file

description: third description
             ...
author: the third author
date: the date in the third file
```

where the first one is already there and I need to repeat it twice.
How can I tell Word to copy and write in specific points of the document?
I've thought something like the following:(The code probably is not correct, I'll put it there to explaying my idea)

```
For i = 1 To n(number of text file)
    ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(Index).Range.Start                                  
                   End:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(Index+3).Range.End).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(Index+4).Select
    Selection.Paste
Next i
```

the previous was for copying the record.
Now I have to fill that records writing the info after title:, author: and date: of each one, so something like:

```
For i=1 To n
  ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(Index(i)+1).Words(2) = description(i)
  ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(Index(i)+2).Words(2) = author(i)
  ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(Index(i)+3).Words(2) = date(i)
Next i
```

where description, author and date are text string I already have.
Does that make any sense or I'm taking a wrong way? Is there any smarter VBA objects I could use?

Comment: Use bookmarks. I don't know much vba for Word, but I think it's the way to go. http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/WorkWithBookmarks.htm

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't have enough points yet to add this as a comment, where it would actually belong...

Which version of Word are you using?
Do you have any influence on the construction of the template, so that you could, for example, add bookmarks such as iDevelop suggests or possibly ContentControls (would be better)?

If you have no influence then it would be better for you to plan entering the data in each "copy" loop.

Note: I hope you're using Documents.Add to create new documents from the template so that you're not actually changing the template?

Comment: I'm using Word 2013 and I have influence on the template. Actually I'm using the template editing it by hands, according to the new info that have to be added in. I know a little bit about VBA and I wonder, if I add a bookmark for a word, like "myWord", should it be unique through the document?

Comment: Bookmark names MUST be unique, so copy/pasting bookmarks can be tricky. Some versions of Word paste the bookmark, which removes the previous one and others don't paste the bookmark, leaving the original.

Since this is Word 2013 my inclincation would be to use ContentControls. Since the names can be duplicated they won't get lost during copy/paste.